# Change 19.04 theme to 18.04 one?

Tags: 18.04, themes, 19.04

I've recently upgraded my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.04, but 19.04 theme is too "plain" for me. Is it possible to change back to 18.04 one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "theme", I presume you mean icon theme. Ubuntu 19.04 uses Yaru as it's primary icon theme, wheras Ubuntu 18.04 uses Adwaita. If you'd prefer the Adwaita icon theme on your Ubuntu 19.04 computer, do the following:

1) Install the icon theme if not already installed - `sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme-full`.

2) Install GNOME Tweaks - `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.

3) Launch GNOME Tweaks, and go to the "Appearence" tab.

4) You should see the icon theme dropdown. Change it from Yaru to Adwaita.

Immediately you should see the icons change back to what they looked like in 18.04. If they don't immediately change, you may need to logout and log back in.

**EDIT:** Apparently the default 18.04 theme is "ubuntu-mono-dark", however it is (pretty much) identical to Adwaita. If you'd prefer to use this, go for it, however Adwaita should be fine if you want it to feel like 18.04.

Comment: The default icon theme in Ubuntu 18.04 is Ubuntu-mono-dark.

Comment: @JerareYoshi - I have edited the question, however Adwaita is pretty much exactly the same ;)